# In Lightning Select Value is not setting Properly in component Side

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

- I have override "Edit" button with Lightning component.Record contains few drop downs.
- when I click on Edit button Value is coming properly in JavaScript Side and it shows proper value In Lightning component side as well, but it's not setting the value properly in drop down (Attached screen Shot)

Expected value is "License queue" but it shows "TechSupportQueue" value.

```
<aura:attribute name="phoneQOptions" type = "List"/>
<aura:attribute name="phoneQSelected" type = "String"/>
<lightning:select label="What phone Q did the call originate on?" aura:id="What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c" value="{!v.phoneQSelected}">
    <aura:if  isTrue="{!or(v.phoneQSelected==null,v.phoneQSelected=='')}">
        <option value="--None--">--None--</option>
    </aura:if>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.phoneQOptions}" var="item">
        <option value="{!item}">{!item}</option>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

Javascript side:

```
component.set('v.phoneQOptions',temp.phoneQOpts); //Option Values
component.set('v.phoneQSelected', temp.ct.What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c); //setting  the values --> License queue
```

Screen Shot:

[image]

Edit record value is 'License queue' but its setting different values in Drop down.

I am thinking that this line of code overrides the value

```
<option value="{!item}">{!item}</option>
```

For more Information:

Record detail

[image]

After clicking edit button it shows:

[image]

Picklist value of that record

[image]

I have tried like this.still No luck

component.find("What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c").set('v.value',temp.ct.What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c);

Updated Complete Code:

Comp:

```
     <lightning:select label="What phone Q did the call originate on?" aura:id="What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c" value="{!v.phoneQSelected}">
                                <aura:if  isTrue="{!or(v.phoneQSelected==null,v.phoneQSelected=='')}">
                                    <option value="--None--">--None--</option>
                                </aura:if>
                               <aura:iteration items="{!v.phoneQOptions}" var="item">
                                    <option value="{!item}">{!item}</option>
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </lightning:select>



   doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.initializeValues(component,event,helper)
      }
```

helper:

```
  ({
      initializeValues : function(component,event,helper){
    var action = component.get('c.getCTValues');
    action.setParams({
        "calltrackerId":component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
        if(actionResult.getState() == "SUCCESS"){
            var temp = actionResult.getReturnValue();
            component.set('v.phoneQOptions',temp.phoneQOpts);
            component.set('v.caseTypeOptions',temp.caseTypeOptions);
            component.set('v.actualServiceRequestOptions',temp.actualServiceRequestOptions);
            component.set('v.whyCustCallOptions',temp.whyCustCallOptions);
            component.set('v.whyCustCallLevel2Options',temp.whyCustCallLevel2Options);
            component.set('v.actionTakenOptions',temp.actionTakenOptions);
            component.set('v.actionTakenLevel2Options',temp.actionTakenLevel2Options);
            component.set("v.caseLookup",temp.c);
            if(temp.c!=null){
                component.set('v.caseLookupVal',true);
            }
            // component.find("What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c").set('v.value',temp.ct.What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c);
            component.set('v.phoneQSelected',temp.ct.What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c);
            component.set('v.caseTypeSelected',temp.ct.New_Existing_or_Not_Case_Related__c);
            component.set('v.actualServiceRequestSelected',temp.ct.Actual_Service_Request__c);
            component.set('v.whyCustCallSelected',temp.ct.Why_Customer_Called__c);
            component.set('v.whyCustCallLevel2Selected',temp.ct.Why_Customer_Called_Level_2__c);
            component.set('v.actionTakenSelected',temp.ct.Action_Taken__c);
            component.set('v.actionTakenLevel2Selected',temp.ct.Action_level_2_Result__c);
            component.set('v.callTrackerRecord',temp.ct);
            component.set('v.CallTrackerDedependencyList',temp.depList);
            component.set("v.Spinner", false);

        }
```

});
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }

Apex Class:

```
public class GSS_CallTrackControllerUpdate {
  public class Initialize_CT_Values{
    @AuraEnabled
    public case c;
    @AuraEnabled
    public Call_Tracker__c ct;
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c> depList;
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<String> phoneQOpts;
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<String> caseTypeOptions;
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<String>actualServiceRequestOptions;
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<String>whyCustCallOptions;
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<String>whyCustCallLevel2Options;
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<String>actionTakenOptions;
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<String>actionTakenLevel2Options;

}
public class DMLResult{
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean isError;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String errorMessage;
}
public static Initialize_CT_Values icv;
@AuraEnabled
public static Initialize_CT_Values getCTValues(string calltrackerId){
    icv = new Initialize_CT_Values();
    List <case > returncaseList = new List<case> ();
    Call_Tracker__c ct=[select GSS_Call_Tracker_Business_Unit__c,New_Existing_or_Not_Case_Related__c,
                        GSS_Case_Owner_Gss_Business_Unit__c,GSS_Severity__c,Comments__c,
                        What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c,Actual_Service_Request__c,
                        Case_Age_Business_Days__c,SR__c,Action_level_2_Result__c,
                        Why_Customer_Called__c,Why_Customer_Called_Level_2__c,Action_Taken__c
                        from Call_Tracker__c where id=:calltrackerId];
    List <case> lstOfRecords=[select caseNumber  from  case where id=:ct.SR__c];
    if(lstOfRecords.size()>0){
        for (case obj: lstOfRecords) {
            returncaseList.add(obj);
        } 
    }
    if(returncaseList.size()>0){
        icv.c= returncaseList[0];
    }

    Call_Tracker__c ctr = new Call_Tracker__c();
    ctr.What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c=ct.What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c;
    ctr.New_Existing_or_Not_Case_Related__c=ct.New_Existing_or_Not_Case_Related__c;
    ctr.Actual_Service_Request__c=ct.Actual_Service_Request__c;
    ctr.Why_Customer_Called__c=ct.Why_Customer_Called__c;
    ctr.Why_Customer_Called_Level_2__c=ct.Why_Customer_Called_Level_2__c;
    ctr.GSS_Call_Tracker_Business_Unit__c=ct.GSS_Call_Tracker_Business_Unit__c;
    ctr.GSS_Severity__c=ct.GSS_Severity__c;
    ctr.Case_Age_Business_Days__c=ct.Case_Age_Business_Days__c;
    ctr.GSS_Case_Owner_Gss_Business_Unit__c=ct.GSS_Case_Owner_Gss_Business_Unit__c;
    ctr.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Call_Tracker__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('New Call Tracker').getRecordTypeId();
    ctr.Action_Taken__c=ct.Action_Taken__c;
    ctr.Action_level_2_Result__c=ct.Action_level_2_Result__c;
    icv.depList = getDependencyMapping();
    icv.phoneQOpts = getPhoneQValues();
    List<Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c> depList = new List<Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c>();
    depList = [select id,Actual_Service_Request__c,New_Existing_or_Not_Case_Related__c,Why_Customer_Called__c,Why_Customer_Called_Level_2__c,Action_Taken__c,Action_level_2_Result__c from Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c order by Name];
    set<string>actualServiceRequestOptions=new set<string>();
    for(Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c gs:depList){
        if(gs.New_Existing_or_Not_Case_Related__c==ct.New_Existing_or_Not_Case_Related__c){
            actualServiceRequestOptions.add(gs.Actual_Service_Request__c);
        }
    }
    List<string> actualserviceOption=new List<string>(actualServiceRequestOptions);
    icv.actualServiceRequestOptions=actualserviceOption;
    set<String>CustCallOptions = new set<String>();
    for(Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c de:depList){
        CustCallOptions.add(ct.Why_Customer_Called__c);
        if(de.Why_Customer_Called__c==ct.Why_Customer_Called__c){
            CustCallOptions.add(de.Why_Customer_Called__c); 
        }
    }
    List<string> existingcustCallOption=new List<string>(CustCallOptions);
    icv.whyCustCallOptions=existingcustCallOption;
    set<string>whyCustCallLevel2OptionStore=new set<string>();
    for(Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c de:depList){
        whyCustCallLevel2OptionStore.add(ct.Why_Customer_Called_Level_2__c);
        if(de.Why_Customer_Called_Level_2__c==ct.Why_Customer_Called_Level_2__c){
            whyCustCallLevel2OptionStore.add(de.Why_Customer_Called_Level_2__c);
        }
    } 
    List<string>whycustomcalllevel2=new List<string>(whyCustCallLevel2OptionStore);   
    icv.whyCustCallLevel2Options=whycustomcalllevel2;
    set<string>actionstoreOption=new set<string>();
    for(Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c de:depList){
        actionstoreOption.add(ct.Action_Taken__c);
        if(de.Action_Taken__c==ct.Action_Taken__c)  {
            actionstoreOption.add(ct.Action_Taken__c);
        }
    }
    List<string>actionTakenStore=new List<string>(actionstoreOption); 
    icv.actionTakenOptions=actionTakenStore;
    set<string>actionTakenLevel2=new set<string>();
    for(Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c de:depList){
        actionTakenLevel2.add(de.Action_level_2_Result__c);
        if(de.Action_level_2_Result__c==ct.Action_level_2_Result__c)  {
            actionTakenLevel2.add(de.Action_level_2_Result__c);
        }
    }
    List<string>actionTakenLevel2Store=new List<string>(actionTakenLevel2);
    icv.actionTakenLevel2Options=actionTakenLevel2Store;
    icv.ct = ctr;
    icv.caseTypeOptions = getCaseTypeValues();
    return icv;
}
public static List<Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c> getDependencyMapping() {      
    List<Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c> depList = new List<Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c>();
    depList = [select id,Actual_Service_Request__c,New_Existing_or_Not_Case_Related__c,Why_Customer_Called__c,Why_Customer_Called_Level_2__c,Action_Taken__c,Action_level_2_Result__c from Gss_Call_Tracker_Dependency_List__c order by Name];
    return depList;
}
public static List<String> getPhoneQValues() {      
    List<String> phoneQ = new List<String>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =
        Call_Tracker__c.What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
    {
        phoneQ.add(f.getLabel());
    }       
    return phoneQ;
}
public static List<String> getCaseTypeValues() {      
    List<String> caseTypeOptions = new List<String>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =
        Call_Tracker__c.New_Existing_or_Not_Case_Related__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
    {
        caseTypeOptions.add(f.getLabel());
    }       
    return caseTypeOptions;
}
@AuraEnabled
public static string UpdateCallTracker(Call_Tracker__c callTrack){
    update callTrack;
    return 'success';
}
```

}

I have tried like this but still not working as expected:

```
   <lightning:select label="What phone Q did the call originate on?" aura:id="What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c" value="{!v.phoneQSelected}">
                                <aura:if  isTrue="{!or(v.phoneQSelected==null,v.phoneQSelected=='')}">
                                    <option value="--None--">--None--</option>
                                </aura:if>
                               <aura:iteration items="{!v.phoneQOptions}" var="item">

                                  <option text="{!item}" value="{!item}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>

                                </aura:iteration>
                            </lightning:select>
```

Comment: Can you show the code that's trying to show the selected values?  Also, `component.set('v.phoneQSelected', temp.ct.What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c);` - not sure why you're doing this.  Once you select a value in `lightning:select` element, you should be able to access it with `component.get("v. phoneQSelected");` without doing a `.set()`

Comment: I need to set the  value of the record..I'm using it for edit button functionality... Record contains license queue as the value..I have override lightning component with edit button..

Comment: Is the field value on the record actually part of the picklist value set?

Comment: Sorry its picklist field in that record

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is most commonly seen because the value set in the Lightning component from the record data doesn't actually correspond to any of the picklist values, as represented in the `<option>` components contained in `<lightning:select>`.

Here, your code is exclusively using the picklist value *label* rather than populating both the label and the API value. This opens up an additional possibility for issues: if your picklist entry's API value, which is what's stored on the record, doesn't match the associated label, your record data won't match any entry in your `<lightning:select>`.

For a pattern that is resilient against this issue, see the Lightning Component Library's [`<lightning:select>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleSelectDynamic) entry, under the "Dropdown Menu with Dynamic Options" example:

```
<lightning:select name="colorId" label="Select a color:" aura:id="colorId" value="{!v.selectedValue}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="option">
        <option text="{!option.label}" value="{!option.id}" selected="{!option.selected}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

In your case, you'd use the picklist entry's label as the `text` attribute and its API value as the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As David Reed Pointed Out,check the value you expect is there in the options.Even after you are not getting the value.In the `doInit` try explicitly setting up the value like below

```
component.find("What_phone_queue_did_the_call_originate__c").set('v.value',component.get("v.phoneQSelected"));
```